# Is there a name for wrinkling and skin peeling on a single fingertip?

Tags: dermatology, fingers, dry-skin, desquamation-skin-peeling

Is there a name for chronic, painless wrinkling that progresses to peeling (without any blistering) in one single location?

I am curious if this is a known condition, as I would like to learn more about it, but do not know its name to research it. For me, it has occurred only on one or two fingers during the last year.

The photos below should clarify what I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65095/discussion-between-none-and-narusan).

Comment: The medical term for wrinkled skin is rhytidermia (rhyti/dermia).  However it looks like more may be going on. I have a few questions and will respond once I get some time.

Comment: It looks like it could be Coxsakie virus healing. If you were sick with a fever and sore throat, the cause could have been coxsakie. Once you're feeling better, the skin on your fingers/hands/feet begin to peel.